# Insert button LIKE on a facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I work for a web agency in Paris. We develop a facebook app, and i need to know if it's OK/allow if we insert a "LIKE" button directly in this application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the facebook Like button directly. [Read this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Comment: You sure i can integrate a like button in my app and people can click on?